# Error Type 'MyClass" has no Member on "onTimer'

Tags: swift

I copied the following code from Github in order to get more experience with playground but I keep getting an error

> Type **'MyClass" has no Member on "onTimer'**!

I tried to look at previous messages to find a solution, unfortunately, I couldn't. If possible can you please help me to solve it. Thanks

```
import UIKit

class MyClass {

    func startTimer() {
        Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.onTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)   
    }

    @objc func onTimer(timer:Timer!) {
        print("Timer here")
    }
}

var anInstance = MyClass()

anInstance.startTimer()

CFRunLoopRun()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to ( Swift 4.2 )

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:2, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

---

```
@objc func onTimer(_ timer:Timer)
```

Verify also if you need `repeats: true)` instead of `repeats: false)`

Comment: Or simply change the selector to `#selector(onTimer)` and leave the method signature as-is.